# Else condition never being triggered

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

This is a part of my partial view -

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" placeholder="Email Address" required/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a part of my controller -

```
var re = /[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/;

self.email = document.getElementById("email");

angular.element(self.email).on("input", function () {
    console.log("Inside event");
    if(self.email.value != re) {
        var closest3 = self.email.closest('div');
        closest3.className += " has-error";
    }

    else {
        closest3.className += " has-success";   
    }
});
```

Why is the `else` condition never being triggered. I am giving the input `characters@characters.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing the string with the regular expression, which will almost certainly always be different.  You instead need to test that the regex matches:

```
if(!re.test(self.email.value)) {
```

There are a few other issues with the code as presented though.  I've moved the declaration and initialisation of `closest3` so that it's available in the `else` block correctly.  You should also remove the "wrong" class in each block to ensure correct behaviour, otherwise it will end up having both classes applied.  I've used the `classList` functionality to do so, but depending on your environment you may need to use a [different method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/791010) of doing so, as it's a [fairly modern property](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList) (older versions of IE will fail).

```
var closest3 = self.email.closest('div');
if(!re.test(self.email.value)) {
    closest3.classList.remove("has-success");
    closest3.className += " has-error";
} else {
    closest3.classList.remove("has-error");
    closest3.className += " has-success";   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because that is not how regular expressions work.

You want to use [`re.test(str)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) or [`str.match(re)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`str.match(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in your if condition :

```
 if(!self.email.value.match(re))
```